# How can I select a random numbers from an array in matlab in a repeating way?

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I have an array name time with 1 row and 1000 columns.

*time=[5,6,7,2,8,1,3,9......]*

I want to call randomly any values from that array. Following is my working algorithm.

*time2 = any random values from time*

*time3 = any random values from time*

*time4 = (time2 + time3)/2*

*time5 = any random value from time*

*common time = 5*;

*time6 = common time - time5*;

*time7 = time4 + time6*

**I have to store the values of *time7* and have to repeat this process for 1000 times**. That I can get the 1000 times time7 values.

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: what is **time1** ? . You've not mentioned it

Comment: Sorry, it would be time4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
len = length(time); % length of the vector
time7 = zeros(1,len) ;  % initilaize the vector time7 to store your time7
common_time = 5;
for iValue = 1:len
  % randi used to get a random value   
  time2 = time(randi([1, len], 1));
  time3 = time(randi([1, len], 1));
  time4 = (time2 + time3)/2;
  time5 = time(randi([1, len], 1));
  time6 = common_time - time5;
  time7(iValue) = time4 - time6;
end
```